# ViewPager child Fragments empty

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-viewpager

I have a `ViewPager` hosted inside a `Fragment`. As a test, I initialize it with three fragments of the same class as the following:

```
mAdapter = new GenericFragmentPagerAdapter(ChildFragmentManager);
mAdapter.Add(frag1);
mAdapter.Add(frag2);
mAdapter.Add(frag3);

mViewPager = Activity.FindViewById<ViewPager>(Resource.Id.fragment_navigation_viewpager);
mViewPager.Adapter = mAdapter;

mTabLayout = Activity.FindViewById<TabLayout>(Resource.Id.tab_layout);
mTabLayout.SetupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
```

Since my `Fragment` objects will be dynamically added to the `ViewPager`, my `GenericFragmentPagerAdapter` extends `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`.

The `Fragment` hosting the `ViewPager` is instantiated inside my `Activity` that hosts a `NavigationView` as follows:

```
NavigationFragment fragment = NavigationFragment.NewInstance();
SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction().
            Replace(Resource.Id.activity_main_content_container,fragment).
            Commit();
```

My problem is: the three fragments are added correctly to the `ViewPager`, but `frag1` and `frag3` appear empty whereas `frag2` shows the contents correctly. Running the debugger, `frag1` and `frag3` do get instantiated correctly so I don't see why they should appear empty.

Apparently, when using nested Fragments, the adapter should be initialized using `getChildFragmentManager()`. Sadly, I still get the same effect as if using `getSupportFragmentManager()`.

Am I missing something, or is there a way to debug the problem?

**Edit**

I managed to get a better idea of the problem that is occurring. For some reason, If my fragment extends `ListFragment` the `ViewPager` gets loaded properly and displays its children. However, if I use normal `Fragment` then the problem occurs. Honestly, I have no clue why, so I provided the code below in case someone would like to try it out.

MainAcitivty.cs

```
namespace App
{
    [Activity(Label = "TestActivity", Theme = "@style/FM360MaterialTheme",
        ConfigurationChanges = Android.Content.PM.ConfigChanges.Orientation | Android.Content.PM.ConfigChanges.ScreenSize)]
    public class TestActivity : FragmentActivity
    {
        TabLayout mTabLayout;
        ViewPager mViewPager;
        GenericFragmentPagerAdapter mAdapter;
        static FMNavigation mFMNavigation;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Create your application here
            // Set our view from the "startup" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.fragment_navigation);

            InitializeNavigation();
        }

        private void InitializeNavigation()
        {
            ProgressDialog progressDialog = ProgressDialog.Show(
                this,
                GetString(Resource.String.Initializing),
                GetString(Resource.String.one_moment)
                );

            new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate {

                // Here the mFMNavigation variable is initialized
                // because it required downloaded data from the internet.

                RunOnUiThread(() =>
                {
                    progressDialog.Dismiss();

                    // If no error occured, initialize UI components.
                    InitializeUserInterface();
                });
            })).Start();
        }

        private void InitializeUserInterface()
        {
            string fragmentTitle = "Test Fragment Title";

            // Items that will be inserted inside the adapter.
            var datasource = mFMNavigation.CurrentItem.Datasource;

            NavigationListFragment f1 = NavigationListFragment.NewInstance(
                datasource,
                mFMNavigation,
                "Title 1");

            NavigationListFragment f2 = NavigationListFragment.NewInstance(
                datasource,
                mFMNavigation,
                "Title 2");

            mAdapter = new GenericFragmentPagerAdapter(SupportFragmentManager);
            mAdapter.Add(f1);
            mAdapter.Add(f2);

            mViewPager = FindViewById<ViewPager>(Resource.Id.fragment_navigation_viewpager);
            mViewPager.Adapter = mAdapter;

            mTabLayout = FindViewById<TabLayout>(Resource.Id.tab_layout);
            mTabLayout.SetupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
        }
    }
}
```

GenericFragmentPagerAdapter.cs

```
    using Android.Support.V4.App;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    namespace Adapters
    {
        public class GenericFragmentPagerAdapter : FragmentStatePagerAdapter
        {
        private List<Fragment> mFragments;

        public GenericFragmentPagerAdapter (FragmentManager fm) : base(fm)
        {
            mFragments = new List<Fragment> ();
        }

        public void Add(Fragment fragment)
        {
            if (!mFragments.Contains (fragment))
                mFragments.Add (fragment);
        }

        public void Remove(Fragment fragment) 
        {
            if (mFragments.Contains (fragment))
                mFragments.Remove (fragment);
        }

        public void RemoveAt(int position)
        {
            if (mFragments.Count <= position)
                return;
            mFragments.RemoveAt(position);
        }

        public void RemoveUntil(int position)
        {
            position++;
            while (mFragments.Count > position)
                mFragments.RemoveAt(position);
        }

        public override int Count { get { return mFragments.Count; }}

        public override Fragment GetItem(int position) { return mFragments [position]; }

        public override int GetItemPosition(Java.Lang.Object item) { return PositionNone; }

        public override Java.Lang.ICharSequence GetPageTitleFormatted(int position)
        {
            Fragment f = mFragments[position];
            if (f is NavigationListFragment)
            {
                NavigationListFragment listFragment = (NavigationListFragment)f;
                return new Java.Lang.String(listFragment.FragmentTitle);
            }
            return new Java.Lang.String("");
        }
    }
}
```

NavigationListFragment.cs

```
namespace App.Fragments
{
    public class NavigationListFragment : Fragment
    {

        List<FMNavigationListItem> mDatasource;
        FMNavigation mFMNavigation;
        string mFragmentTitle;
        ExpandableListviewAdapter mAdapter;

        public NavigationListFragment()
        {

        }

        public static NavigationListFragment NewInstance(List<FMNavigationListItem> items, FMNavigation navigation, string fragmentTitle)
        {
            NavigationListFragment f = new NavigationListFragment();
            f.mFMNavigation = navigation;
            f.mDatasource = items;
            f.mFragmentTitle = fragmentTitle;
            return f;
        }

       public override void OnActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            RetainInstance = true;
            InitializeListView();
        }

        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            return inflater.Inflate(
                Resource.Layout.fragment_navigation_list,
                container,
                false);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        void InitializeListView()
        {
            ExpandableListView listView = Activity.FindViewById<ExpandableListView>(
                Resource.Id.fragment_navigation_list_expandable_listview);

            // "Remove" listview and set empty state.
            if (mDatasource == null || mDatasource.Count <= 0)
            {
                TextView emptyView = Activity.FindViewById<TextView>(
                    Resource.Id.fragment_navigation_list_empty_textview);
                emptyView.Text = GetString(Resource.String.empty_list_text);
                listView.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
                return;
            }

            // Here we build a list of groupable items based on the 
            // data source given.
            List<ExpandableItem> groupItems = new List<ExpandableItem>();
            foreach (var dataItem in mDatasource)
            {
                string className = mFMNavigation.NameOfClassId(dataItem.ClassId);

                // Attempt to find the group that has the same class name.
                // If it exists add the data item to the group. Otherwise
                // create a new group and add the item.
                ExpandableItem groupItem = groupItems.Find(x => x.GroupTitle.Equals(className));
                if (groupItem == null)
                {
                    ExpandableItem item = new ExpandableItem();
                    item.GroupTitle = className;
                    item.ChildItems = new List<FMNavigationListItem>();
                    item.ChildItems.Add(dataItem);
                    groupItems.Add(item);
                    continue;
                }
                groupItem.ChildItems.Add(dataItem);
            }
            mAdapter = new ExpandableListviewAdapter(Activity, groupItems);

            listView.SetAdapter(mAdapter);

            }



        #region Fragment Properties
        public string FragmentTitle
        {
            get { return mFragmentTitle; }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

ExpandableListviewAdapter.cs

```
namespace App.Adapters
{
    class ExpandableListviewAdapter : BaseExpandableListAdapter
    {
        private Activity mContext;
        private List<ExpandableItem> mDataItems;

       public ExpandableListviewAdapter(Activity context, List<ExpandableItem> items)
            : base()
        {
            mContext = context;
            mDataItems = items;

            // Sort the groups and all of its child elements alphabetically.
            SortDataItems();
        }

        void SortDataItems()
        {
            // Sort each group alphabetically.
            mDataItems.Sort(delegate (ExpandableItem e1, ExpandableItem e2) 
            {
                return e1.GroupTitle.CompareTo(e2.GroupTitle);
            });

            // Iterate over each group of items and sort the 
            // children alphabetically.
            foreach (var d in mDataItems)
            {
                d.ChildItems.Sort(delegate (FMNavigationListItem i1, FMNavigationListItem i2)
                {
                    return i1.DisplayAttributes[0].CompareTo(i2.DisplayAttributes[0]);
                });
            }
        }

        public override View GetChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, bool isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            if (convertView == null)
                convertView = mContext.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.adapter_expandable_listview_listitem, null);

            FMNavigationListItem item = mDataItems[groupPosition].ChildItems[childPosition];
            convertView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.adapter_expandable_listview_listitem_textview1).Text = item.DisplayAttributes[0];
            convertView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.adapter_expandable_listview_listitem_textview2).Text = item.DisplayAttributes[1];
            convertView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.adapter_expandable_listview_listitem_textview3).Text = item.DisplayAttributes[2];

            ImageButton i = convertView.FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.adapter_expandable_listview_listitem_overflow_button);
            i.Click += OverflowButtonClicked;
            return convertView;
        }

        private void OverflowButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(
                mContext,
                "Overflow button clicked!",
                ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }

        public override View GetGroupView(int groupPosition, bool isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            if (convertView == null)
                convertView = mContext.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.adapter_expandable_listview_header, null);

            // We expand all child objects from the group per default.
            // Normal default ist that all children are collapsed.
            ExpandableListView listView = (ExpandableListView)parent;
            listView.ExpandGroup(groupPosition);

            // Set the header title to be the group title.
            ExpandableItem item = mDataItems[groupPosition];
            convertView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.adapter_expandable_listview_header_textview).Text = item.GroupTitle;
            return convertView;
        }

        public override int GroupCount
        {
            get
            {
                return mDataItems.Count;
            }
        }

        public override bool HasStableIds
        {
            get
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        public override Java.Lang.Object GetChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override long GetChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
        {
            return childPosition;
        }

        public override int GetChildrenCount(int groupPosition)
        {
            return mDataItems[groupPosition].ChildItems.Count;
        }

        public override bool IsChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public override Java.Lang.Object GetGroup(int groupPosition)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override long GetGroupId(int groupPosition)
        {
            return groupPosition;
        }

        public FMNavigationListItem ChildAt(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
        {
            return mDataItems[groupPosition].ChildItems[childPosition];
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    internal class ExpandableItem
    {
        public string GroupTitle;
        public List<FMNavigationListItem> ChildItems;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please share a basic demo that can reproduce the issue?

Comment: I'm still experimenting and trying out some things. I'll let you know if ever things become clearer.

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT Can I provide a test project solution, or should I post code that reproduces the error?

Comment: You can provide a test project or post the code that reproduces the error or do both.

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT I updated the question to include the relevant code in case you'd like to give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I fixed my problem. As stated above, the problem was not tied to the `FragmentManager`. I figured out that the `ViewPager` works perfectly when extending the `ListFragment` class and using a normal `ListView`. If I used a normal fragment with an `ExpandableListView`, the `ViewPager` started acting weird and displaying empty fragments (still no idea why).

My solution is to create an adapter for the normal `ListView` that supports section headers using this [this blog post](http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/listview-with-section-header-in-android) that I found  as a reference.

Here's my adapter in case anyone needs one:

**SectionedHeaderListViewAdaper.cs**

```
namespace YourNamespace
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Used to pass groups of objects to the adapter.
    /// </summary>
    internal class ExpandableItem
    {
        public string HeaderTitle;
        public List<FMNavigationListItem> ChildItems;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Used internally by the adapter.
    /// </summary>
    internal class SectionedHeaderListItem
    {
        public string HeaderTitle;
        public FMNavigationListItem Item;

        public SectionedHeaderListItem(string headerTitle, FMNavigationListItem item)
        {
            HeaderTitle = headerTitle;
            Item = item;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    class SectionedHeaderListViewAdaper : BaseAdapter
    {
        const int TypeItem = 0;
        const int TypeSeperator = 1;

        LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
        List<SectionedHeaderListItem> mDataItems;
        List<int> mSectionPositions;

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="context"></param>
        /// <param name="items"></param>
        public SectionedHeaderListViewAdaper(Context context, List<ExpandableItem> items)
        {
            mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
            mSectionPositions = new List<int>();

            // Sort each item via header title.
            List<ExpandableItem> dataItems = items;
            dataItems.Sort(delegate (ExpandableItem e1, ExpandableItem e2)
            {
                return e1.HeaderTitle.CompareTo(e2.HeaderTitle);
            });

            // Sort each child item alphabetically.
            foreach (var d in dataItems)
            {
                d.ChildItems.Sort(delegate (FMNavigationListItem i1, FMNavigationListItem i2)
                {
                    return i1.DisplayAttributes[0].CompareTo(i2.DisplayAttributes[0]);
                });
            }

            // Merge all items into one big list.
            mDataItems = new List<SectionedHeaderListItem>();
            int index = 0;
            foreach (var expandableItem in dataItems)
            {
                // Represents a section
                mDataItems.Add(new SectionedHeaderListItem(
                    expandableItem.HeaderTitle,
                    null));
                mSectionPositions.Add(index);
                index++;

                // Now add the child items for the section
                foreach (var dataItem in expandableItem.ChildItems)
                {
                    mDataItems.Add(new SectionedHeaderListItem(
                       expandableItem.HeaderTitle,
                       dataItem));
                    index++;
                }
            }
        }

        public override Java.Lang.Object GetItem(int position)
        {
            return position;
        }

        public override long GetItemId(int position)
        {
            return position;
        }

        public FMNavigationListItem ItemAt(int position)
        {
            return mDataItems[position].Item;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// One view for the header and another for
        /// the normal cells.
        /// </summary>
        public override int ViewTypeCount
        {
            get
            {
                return 2;
            }
        }

        public override int GetItemViewType(int position)
        {
            if (mSectionPositions.Contains(position))
                return TypeSeperator;
            return TypeItem;
        }

        public override int Count
        {
            get
            {
                return mDataItems.Count;
            }
        }

        public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            SectionedHeaderListViewAdaperViewHolder holder = null;
            int rowType = GetItemViewType(position);

            // Inflate the correct layout
            if (convertView == null)
            {
                holder = new SectionedHeaderListViewAdaperViewHolder();
                switch(rowType)
                {
                    case TypeItem:
                        convertView = mLayoutInflater.Inflate(
                            Resource.Layout.adapter_expandable_listview_listitem, 
                            null);
                       break;
                    case TypeSeperator:
                        convertView = mLayoutInflater.Inflate(
                            Resource.Layout.adapter_expandable_listview_header,
                            null);
                        break;
                }
                convertView.Tag = (SectionedHeaderListViewAdaperViewHolder)convertView.Tag;
            }
            else
            {
                holder = (SectionedHeaderListViewAdaperViewHolder)convertView.Tag;
            }

            //Populate UI components
            SectionedHeaderListItem item = mDataItems[position];
            switch (rowType)
            {
                case TypeItem:
                    // Horrible code incomming
                    holder.DispAttsTextViews = new List<TextView>();
                    holder.DispAttsTextViews.Add(convertView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.adapter_expandable_listview_listitem_textview1));
                    holder.DispAttsTextViews.Add(convertView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.adapter_expandable_listview_listitem_textview2));
                    holder.DispAttsTextViews.Add(convertView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.adapter_expandable_listview_listitem_textview3));
                    holder.DispAttsTextViews[0].Text = item.Item.DisplayAttributes[0];
                    holder.DispAttsTextViews[1].Text = item.Item.DisplayAttributes[1];
                    holder.DispAttsTextViews[2].Text = item.Item.DisplayAttributes[2];
                    break;
                case TypeSeperator:
                    holder.HeaderTextView = convertView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.adapter_expandable_listview_header_textview);
                    holder.HeaderTextView.Text = item.HeaderTitle;
                    break;
            }
            return convertView;
        }
    }

    class SectionedHeaderListViewAdaperViewHolder : Java.Lang.Object
    {
        public TextView HeaderTextView { get; set; }
        public List<TextView> DispAttsTextViews { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**adapter_expandable_listview_listitem.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">
        <TextView
            android:text="Rüttenscheider Stern"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/adapter_expandable_listview_listitem_textview1"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textColor="@color/textColorPrimary" />
        <TextView
            android:text="Essen"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/adapter_expandable_listview_listitem_textview1"
            android:id="@+id/adapter_expandable_listview_listitem_textview2"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
        <TextView
            android:text="Rüttenscheiderstraße"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/adapter_expandable_listview_listitem_textview2"
            android:id="@+id/adapter_expandable_listview_listitem_textview3"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:id="@+id/adapter_expandable_listview_listitem_overflow_button"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_dots_vertical_grey600_18dp"
            android:background="@null" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/material_grey_300" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**adapter_expandable_listview_header**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/adapter_expandable_listview_header_textview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="Header"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textColor="@color/textColorSecondary"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```